# Understanding A Disavantage of OOP

Tags: oop

What did the author mean by this:

> “The problem with object-oriented languages is they’ve got all this
>   implicit environment that they carry around with them. You wanted a
>   banana but what you got was a gorilla holding the banana and the
>   entire jungle.”

It sounds like a rather damning criticism of OOP but why?

Comment: If you can't understand from the context it was written, then the author has done a pretty poor job. If there is no context provided, then treat it as useless rhetoric.

Comment: Understood. But what is meant by code having an implicit environment?

Comment: This is why good object oriented design avoids class coupling. Instead of the definition a Gorilla, you should only need some minimal interface to a BananaHolder in order to be able to use Banana. That aside, this question does not follow the StackOverflow rules for [asking](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I'm having a heck of a time finding the original source for this quote.  Comes up with a lot of hits, but looks like they're just snippets.  Can anyone find it?

Comment: @jrahhali It's from Coders at Work: Reflections on the Craft of Programming by Peter Seibel. See [page 213](https://books.google.es/books?id=nneBa6-mWfgC&lpg=PA203&ots=gFytDgRS4B&dq=%22CODERS%20AT%20WORK%22%20GORILLA&pg=PA213#v=onepage&q=GORILLA&f=false).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In OOP, it's easy and tempting to make anything dependant of everything:

```
class Banana {
   Gorilla WhoHoldsYou() { return gorilla; }
   Gorilla gorilla;
}

class Gorilla {
   Jungle WhereDoYouLive { return jungle; }
   Jungle jungle;
}
```

This is not great for code reuse, because you also need the `Gorilla` and `Jungle` classes to use a `Banana`.

A better approach (from a code-reuse perspective) would have been to have a separate map of Banana -> Gorilla and Gorilla -> Jungle, such that the `Banana` class does not need to know the `Gorilla` class.